# Label registers in SQL associated with an ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sorting, labeling

I have a set of clusters in SQL associated with an average value like this:

| Cluster | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Cluster5 | 10 |
| Cluster3 | 8 |
| Cluster4 | 4 |
| Cluster2 | 2 |
| Cluster1 | 1 |

The name of the cluster doesn't have any relation with his value and I need to label them according to it like this:

| Cluster | Value | Cluster label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cluster5 | 10 | 1 |
| Cluster3 | 8 | 2 |
| Cluster4 | 4 | 3 |
| Cluster2 | 2 | 4 |
| Cluster1 | 1 | 5 |

There is no limit for the number of clusters; it has to have more than 1 and less than 6. (1 < # of clusters < 6)

Thank you

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: "_less than 5_", and still you have Cluster label 5... What's expected to happen if there are less than 2, or more than 5?

Comment: SQLite but I can use MySQL in any version

Comment: There is a previous check with the number of clusters; at this point is impossible to have more than 5 or less than 2 clusters.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * , row_number() over (order by value desc) Clusterlabel
from table
```